# Differences between private inheritance and composition

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, composition

Other questions already answered what they are and when to use them. I am especially interested how private inheritance and composition differ on a much deeper technical level. So this question is specifically tagged C++, because the low level details are language dependent.

For me, I inherit non-virtually from a single base class. The base class itself does not inherit from any other class. Let's also assume the base class has at least one member, so we don't have to worry about empty base optimization.

In terms of memory layout, object construction/destruction order, defined operators (assign, copy, move, ...) and other criteria that I have not thought of, are there any differences between the two approaches?